# Ms Access Relink to 2 separate backends from 1 frontend Programmatically

Tags: vba, ms-access

I use two access databases.  1 Rolodex (Client Info and related jobs, etc) - 2 is Timeclock (Employee timesheets with hours, rates etc and all necessary info for creating the various forms and reports for distribution). From time to time I have to take the above home to make changes to the frontend.  I use the built in Linked Table Manager and would like to be able to use vba to automate the process.
All frontend and backends are located in the same folder at Office (on the server) or my Desktop when I’m at home so I’m only dealing with a total of 2 locations, 2 frontend and 2 backends.  (Right now, I’m just testing my home usage (C) not the server in the office (G) as I don’t know what the path is yet.

I created a table that contains 4 records:
'C:\users\bobbye\desktop\rolodex_be
'C:\users\bobbye\desktop\timeclock_be
'G:\ rolodex_be
'G:\timeclock_be

The Rolodex uses one backend called Rolodex_be.  I created a form to select a file and run a relink function that I found online and it works fine.

The Timeclock uses both the Timeclock_be and the Rolodex_be backends.  I copied the same function, table and form to Timeclock.  I selected the timeclock_be on the form thinking it would run through the function and connect to the timeclock_be (It didn’t) and then I could run it again to connect the Rolodex_be.  But it never even got that far.
So how do I get Timeclock FE to connect to both backends?
I’m not a programmer so please keep your response as simple as possible please.  Thanks

Here is the function I called onclick event on the form:

(I made LnkDataBase Public so that I could change the name of the backend as needed)

```
Sub Relinktables()
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim strTable As String
    Set dbs = CurrentDb()
    For Each tdf In dbs.TableDefs
        If Len(tdf.Connect) > 1 Then 'Only relink linked tables
            If tdf.Connect <> ";DATABASE=" & LnkDataBase Then 'only relink tables if the are not linked right
            If Left(tdf.Connect, 4) <> "ODBC" Then 'Don't want to relink any ODBC tables
                strTable = tdf.Name
                dbs.TableDefs(strTable).Connect = ";DATABASE=" & LnkDataBase
                dbs.TableDefs(strTable).RefreshLink
            End If
        End If
    End If
   Next tdf
End Sub
```

Comment: Why didn't you get that far - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Did you step debug? What is value of LnkDataBase? I tested your code and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use UNC path for office server connection and drive mapping is irrelevant. Can even use it for home PC path.

Could replace just part of connection string that changes and since both backends are in same folder on your PC, it's simple. Here is procedure I use:

```
Sub FixLinks()
Dim td As tableDef
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim strOld As String
Dim strNew As String

'replace the following strings as needed
strNew = "C:\path\"
strOld = "\\unc path\"

Set db = CurrentDb
For Each td In db.TableDefs
    If td.Connect <> "" Then
        If InStr(td.Connect, strOld) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print td.Name
            Debug.Print "Old Link: " & td.Connect
            td.Connect = Replace(td.Connect, strOld, strNew)
            td.RefreshLink
            Debug.Print "New Link: " & td.Connect
        End If
    End If
Next td
db.TableDefs.Refresh
End Sub
```

I don't run this from a form. Code is in general module so I open VBA editor, adjust path strings and Run from ribbon. You could modify it to take arguments and call from a form.